# what is ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS meaning

Tags: xcode, variables, tags

I am confused with $ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS variable in the Xcode -> build settings -> Architectures

What is $ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS variable meaning in the xcode?
Where this variable is set?
How I could echo this variable and see the exactly content?

Answer (score 8):

`$ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS` is defined by Xcode and its associated tools and libraries. The value has changed over time as the iOS devices evolved with different processors.

To get the value (along with others) you can try the following from terminal in your project's directory:

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -project YOUR_PROJECT_HERE.xcodeproj | grep ARCHS
```

Sample output:

```
ARCHS = armv7
ARCHS_STANDARD = armv7 arm64
ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT = armv7 arm64
ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT = armv7
ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT = arm64
ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT = armv7 arm64
ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS = armv7 arm64
VALID_ARCHS = armv7 arm64
```

Replace `YOUR_PROJECT_HERE.xcodeproj` with the name of your project. The `grep` filter in the example will show just variables related to ARCHS. If you want to see all of the variables (some defined by Xcode, others from your project) you can leave off the `grep` command:

```
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -project YOUR_PROJECT_HERE.xcodeproj
```

The list will be long but thorough, and useful to enhance and troubleshoot build scripts.